# Bulk image importing from folders

Tags: media, media-library, gallery

I have hundreds of different named folders with various amounts of images inside each. I uploaded the folders to the wp-content/uploads directory. How can I import all at once into the media library (or the nextGEN gallery), and have the folder names be made into gallery names for each set of images?

Comment: loop through your directory and use `wp_insert_attachment`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

Comment: @Kudratullah you should turn your comment into an answer so it can be accepted as such, since it's the only answer so far (after 6 years)!

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn i have added a comprehensive answer to op's query. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have upload images in `wp-content/uploads/some-image-dir`.

you can iterate content with `scandir` or `glob` and pass the file to `wp_insert_attachment` with appropriate arguments adding those files/images as attachments in posts table.

Here's a little wp-cli snippet for better understanding.
add this to your plugin or theme (index.php), then run from terminal using `wp scan-attachments` command.

```php
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
    WP_CLI::add_command( 'scan-attachments', function () {
        $upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
        if ( $upload_dir['error'] ) {
            WP_CLI::error( $upload_dir['error'] );
        }

        wpse_271278_files_to_attachments(
            '/path/to/wp-content/uploads/some-image-dir',
            $upload_dir['basedir'],
            $upload_dir['baseurl'],
            [
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png',
                'webp'
            ]
        );
    } );

    /**
     * Scan through directory and create attachments recursively.
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @param string $base_dir
     * @param string $base_url
     * @param array|null $exclude_ext
     *
     * @return void
     * @link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#107117
     *
     */
    function wpse_271278_files_to_attachments( string $dir, string $base_dir, string $base_url, array|null $allowed_ext = null ): void {
        $dir  = untrailingslashit( $dir );
        $root = scandir( $dir );

        if ( ! $root ) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ( $root as $value ) {
            if ( $value === '.' || $value === '..' || $value === '.DS_Store' ) {
                continue;
            }

            $full_path = $dir . '/' . $value;

            if ( is_file( $full_path ) ) {
                $file_name   = wp_basename( $full_path );
                $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype_and_ext( $full_path, $file_name, null );
                $file_ext    = $wp_filetype['ext'] ?? '';
                $file_type   = $wp_filetype['type'] ?? '';

                if ( ! $file_ext || ( $allowed_ext && ! in_array( $file_ext, $allowed_ext ) ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $url        = str_replace( $base_dir, $base_url, $full_path );
                $attachment = wp_insert_attachment(
                    [
                        'post_title'     => $file_name,
                        'post_content'   => $url,
                        'post_mime_type' => $file_type,
                        'guid'           => $url,
                        'context'        => 'import-cli',
                    ],
                    $full_path,
                    0,
                    true
                );

                if ( is_wp_error( $attachment ) ) {
                    WP_CLI::error(
                        sprintf(
                            'Failed to create attachment for file (%1$s). Error: %2$s',
                            $full_path,
                            $attachment->get_error_message()
                        ),
                        false
                    );
                }
                WP_CLI::success( sprintf( 'File imported (#%1$d – %2$s).', $attachment, $full_path ) );
                continue;
            }

            // Running recursively.
            wpse_271278_files_to_attachments( $full_path, $base_dir, $base_url, $allowed_ext );
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use without wp-cli, remove wp-cli specific function calls (E.G `WP_CLI::error()` and `WP_CLI::success()`).

P.S. You might also need to change file permission and ownership of the images.

Edit: if your php version is lower (i'm using 8.3) remove type hints from arguments.